# Mail server run well but shutting down soon when i try a not root user in CentOS7

Tags: linux, centos7

I want turn on the mail server(apache jmail) by normal user(not root user),

so i tried the following step for under 1024 ports.

It runs well when root turns it on.

But it shutting down few second later when normal user turn it on, and it isn't remain any log on server.

I don't under stand why it is happened, and i can't find any solution by googling.

cd /usr/local/java/bin 
setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' java 
cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d 
vi java.conf  --->     /usr/local/java/lib/amd64/jli 
ldconfig

cd ~userId 
chown –R userId:group projectfolder 
cd /volumes 
chown –R userId:group shared

vi /etc/security/limits.conf ---> 
userId             soft    nofile           65535 
userId             hard    nofile           65535

vi .bash_profile ---> 
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

source .bash_profile

Comment: Check your mail server's logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point, you are going to have to start something as root.  You must be root to listen on port 25.  Most mail servers run as root, or they start as root and then fork child processes as an unprivileged user.

Most likely the reason it's failing as a non-root user is that it's getting a "permission denied" on port 25.

If you want to run it as a non-root user, change the configuration to listen to a port above 1024... say 9025 (for example).  Then have your firewall portmap incoming connections to port 25 to port 9025 on your mail host.